# binding info for website with SSL running on IIS on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate

Folks!  I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine running IIS 7.  I'm attempting to create a website that will use SSL.  When I create the website, I choose "https" as 'type', "443" as Port and the correct IP address, but I'm unable to enter the 'Host name' information.  I am able to enter the 'Host name' if I choose "http" as 'type' and '80' as port.  I have a few questions:
1. Is the inability to enter the 'Host name' for a 'https' binding an IIS 7 design or am I doing something wrong?
2. If I'm doing something wrong, how do I enter the hostname information?
3. If I leave both types ('http' and 'https'), does 'http' automatically act as a redirect to https or do I need to configure something else so that it will redirect?
Thanks, in advance, for all your help!
- Charles

Comment: SSL can only be used on an IP, whereas HTTP can use "virtual" domains that serve a different site based on the hostname. With HTTPS you only get the site configured for that IP and SSL. I presume it is this reason why it won't let you use HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jason Taylor is correct. There can only be a single HTTPS site using 443 per IP address so the host name field is completely grayed out and ignored. You can add 2nd and 3rd IP addresses or use non-standard ports to have multiple SSL sites on one server.